# loaded? always returns true for belongs_to associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some geography related classed defined as follows:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class State < Location
  has_many :geographies
  has_many :cities
  has_many :counties
end

class County < Location
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :geographies
  has_many :cities, :through => :geographies, :uniq => true
end    

class City < Location
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :geographies
  has_many :counties, :through => :geographies, :uniq => true
end

class Geography < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :county
end
```

The following console output demonstrates the problem that I'm having.

```
>> County.first.cities.loaded?
=> false
>> County.first.state.loaded?
=> true
```

Looking in the logs I see that when I call state.loaded? it runs a SQL statement to load the state, i.e., the state was not loaded until I "touched" it.  However, when I call cities.loaded? no SQL is executed and false is returned.  This behavior seems inconsistent to me. I searched around a bit on the interwebs and couldn't find anything regarding this so I'm guessing it's my mistake, though, I don't see how.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you can use the Object method instance_variable_get to check to see if a belongs_to association is loaded without triggering the association to be loaded during your check. So...

```
>> c = County.first
=> #<County id: 1, ...>
>> c.instance_variable_get("@state")
=> nil
>> c.state
=> #<State id: 1, ...>
>> c.instance_variable_get("@state")
=> #<State id: 1, ...>
>> c = County.first(:include => :state)
=> #<County id: 1, ...>
>> c.instance_variable_get("@state")
=> #<State id: 1, ...>
```

Comment: You can also use `c.association(:state).loaded?`; it won't load the belongs_to

Answer (score 2):

I think it comes down to the type of relationship being used and the interaction with lazy loading.

When you call **County.first.state**, Rails will load the state object that belongs to the County - there is only one, and therefore a call to .state is actually a call to a 'concrete' object in the database that can be loaded.

However, when you call **County.first.cities**, you are actually calling the relationship collection that belongs to the county object. As you don't actually call on a specific object or set of conditions, Rails is smart enough not to load the collection.

If you said something like:

```
County.first.cities.all
County.first.cities.each
County.first.cities.first
```

Rails would then kick-off the SQL statement and load the data.

Comment: Right, is there a way to know if a belongs_to association has been loaded into memory or not seeing that the loaded? method will always return true?  It seems that the method loaded? is useless for belongs_to associations.